# Importing product listings from Amazon into Magento

Tags: amazon

I am looking to import by book listings from Amazon into Magento

Comment: Do you have a question? Or are you just listing future objectives?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this extension [M2E Pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebay-magento-integration-order-import-and-stock-level-synchronization-also-supports-amazon-rakuten-and-play-com.html) It suppports integration with Ebay and Amazon. It is free of cost. It might help .

Answer (score 1):

Please check Amazon Products Manager: https://web-experiment.info/magento-amazon-products-manager
This Magento plugin allows you to easily import Amazon products into Magento. Note, it uses the Affiliate API, not the Merchant API. You can import any product available for affiliate sales.

New option "Sync ISBN Products" is available for books. Fast and easy import reviews from Amazon to Magento by ISBN.

You can use Merchant ID option. It would set the affiliate link to point to exact merchant offer on Amazon.